# gevent-socketio: several instances of namespace

Tags: python, socket.io, gevent

when creating a socketio app, my server declares a namespace with a class variable

```
class MyNamespace(BaseNamespace):
    _registry = {}
    ...

    def _broadcast(self, event, message):
        for s in self._registry.values():
            s.emit(event, message)

def application(environ, start_response):
    return socketio_manage(environ, {'/socket': MyNamespace})
```

How can I have several connections but to different instances of the namespace?
For example, imagine this is a chat room app and `_registry` stores different people. How can i implement different rooms? where any user in a given room can message each other but not others from other rooms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have rooms as some kind of object, and messages have an address.

An address could be a room, or an individual user.

Rooms should reemit all messages sent to them, to the users in them.

Comment: can you post some pseudo code on how i should setup "application"?